# Address of unique_ptr doesn't change even after std::move

Tags: c++, c++11

I am exploring unique_ptr . I am getting wrong answer than expected , Can anyone help me to find what exactly went wrong here in code .
I am using WSL(windows system for linux) on windows machine .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto revenu_ptr{make_unique<double>(1234.64)};
    cout << "Revenue ptr---------" << endl;
    cout << "Original " << &revenu_ptr << " " << *revenu_ptr<< endl;

    auto revenue_ptr_move = std::move(revenu_ptr);
    cout << "After Move " << &revenu_ptr << endl;
    cout << "Revenue_ptr_move---------" << endl;
    cout << "Moved Adderess " << &revenue_ptr_move<< endl;
    cout << "Moved Value " << *revenue_ptr_move << endl;
}
```

```
Expected Output : 
Revenue ptr---------
Original 0x7ffd442e9618 1234.64
After Move 0x0
Revenue_ptr_move---------
Moved Adderess 0x7ffd442e9618
Moved Value 1234.64
```

But I am getting this wrong output , after move operation adderss should become zero but it is pointing at same memory location . and new adderess is there in revenue_ptr_move

```
Revenue ptr---------
Original 0x7ffd442e9618 1234.64
After Move 0x7ffd442e9618
Revenue_ptr_move---------
Moved Adderess 0x7ffd442e9620
Moved Value 1234.64
```

Comment: `revenu_ptr` will always have an address in memory, just like if you had `char * foo = NULL;` then `&foo` would be the memory address where the pointer data is. If you were to call `get()` you'd see it point to an address and then 0.

Comment: the address of an object never changes.

Comment: I think your plan was to have something like this: https://godbolt.org/z/ox3qjbTb6

Comment: move is only needs to leave the original object in an "undefined but valid state". It doesn't mean the pointer value has to be changed (just that the original unique_ptr is no longer owner of that address)

Comment: @PepijnKramer: Aside from the question of whether a `std::unique_ptr` with an old value for `get()` would be valid, that particular type does guarantee that moving clears the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&revenu_ptr` is the address of the unique ptr object.

`*revenu_ptr` is the data pointed to.

`revenu_ptr.get()` is the value of the unique ptr object.

You appear to be confusing `&revenu_ptr` with `revenu_ptr.get()`.

This isn't a rare problem.  The "address of a pointer" is not the same as the "value of a pointer".  And the fact that the value of a pointer is *an address* adds to the confusion!

On top of that, the value the pointer POINTS AT is different than the value the pointer HAS.

The pointer has a value that is an address.

The pointer's address is an address.

The pointer's pointed-to value has an address, which is the pointer's value.

```
[&ptr] -> [ptr.get()] -> [7]
```

here we have a (unique) ptr which is pointing at the value 7.

It has an address -- where itself is stored.  It has a value, which is the address of the value 7 it points at.  And it has a pointed-to value, which is an integer with the value 7.